# how to insert incremented primary key and foreign key in java jframe tables?

Tags: java, mysql, jframe

I am new in java and I am trying to insert data into three tables on netbeans jframe. I already created the data on MySql

The first table contains Primary Key

```
create table TraineeDetals(
TraineeID smallint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
FirstName varchar(100) not null,
MiddleName varchar(100) not null,
LastName varchar(100) not null
)
```

and the other table has the foreign key

```
create table CollegeDetails(
collegeName varchar(100) not null,
Specialization varchar(100) not null,
TraineeID smallint unsigned not null,
constraint 'fk_Trainee'
foreign key (TraineeID) references TraineeDetails (TraineeID)
on delete cascade
on update restrict
)
```

Now I want to insert data by using jframe so in the java code I did this

```
   String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql";
   String user="root";
   String pass="root";

   private void 
   SaveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

   try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, 
        pass);
        String sql="Insert into TraineeDetails 
        (FirstName,MiddleName,LastName)values(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst =con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, firstNameTextFiled.getText());
        pst.setString(2, MiddleNameTextField.getText());
        pst.setString(3, LastNameTextField.getText());

        String sql2 = "Insert into CollegeDetails (CollegeName, 
        Specialization,TraineeID)values(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst2 =con.prepareStatement(sql2);

        pst2.setString(1, CollegeNameTextField.getText());
        pst2.setString(2, SpecializationTextField.getText());
        pst.setString(3, TraineeIDTextField.getText());


        pst.executeUpdate();
        pst2.executeUpdate();


        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Insert 
        Successfully");

        clearText();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,e.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

This code shows data only for table TraineeDetails

All data must be added from here and the id has to be auto increment.

[image: All data must be added from here and the id has to be auto increment]

After that, the admin can show data that he added here. Jframe shows data only for TraineeDetails table how can I fix it

[image: jframe shows data only for TraineeDetails table how can I fix it]

Please, what I have to do to insert auto increment Primary key and foreign key and show data together after adding them? And what about my java code, is there something missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can watch this video for better understanding how to do that 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NC6bY2oJr7s

Here is how you can do it ...

First make class lets call it sql.java and import it to your project class library

Write this code in it

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatment;

public class sql {
public void id_incrementtable() {

int id = 1 ;
PreparedStatment ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null ; 
Conectar db = new Conectar() ;
try {
ps = db.getConnection().prepareStatement("select max(id) from your 
tablename");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()) (
id = rs.getint(1) + 1 ; 
)
}catch(Exception ex);

System.out.printin("error"+ex.getMessage());


}
finally ( 
try (
ps.close();
rs.close();
db.desconectar() ;
) catch(Exception ex) ( 

)

}
```

// by running the above you will notice it add auto serial in your tablename  everytime  you save record on the table

// save data button code , you first define sql s = new sql() to read from that // class which been added to your project class reference

sql s = new sql();
int id = s.id_incrementable() ;

// and your place your remaining code here  ... i think you got the idea